# Where is Espresso test reports located?

Tags: android, report, android-espresso

I'm running Espresso for my Android tests in Eclipse. Where is the generated xml/html reports located? Do I need to set anything up in order to get them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Espresso reports for individual tests are generated in $Project_Root/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/

You will get the html reports here by default.

For xml report, you can navigate to this directory: 
$Project_Root/app/build/outputs/androidTest-results/connected/

Answer (score 0):

I had a trouble locating the test reports when running through Android studio.

Finally, I was able to find the reports are recorded in

`~/.AndroidStudio3.4/system/testHistory/<random-key>`

I find the appropriate key ordering the folders by date modified.